# Linking locally a Vue app and a Vue lib --> d.ts issue;

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, .d.ts

I am facing a problem while trying to split my code between a lib and an app.
I want to use **Vuejs** + **TypeScript** + **WebPack**, it seems like a good combination.
I encounter some issues while trying to call in the app anything from the lib. It seems like this is about the **d.ts files**.

```
// powershell output
13:22 Could not find a declaration file for module 'my-lib'. 'path/my-lib.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/my-lib` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'my-lib';`
    11 | // import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
    12 |
  > 13 | import sayHello from "my-lib";
       |                      ^
    14 |
    15 | export default Vue.extend({
    16 |   name: "App",
```

I don't want to bypass problem by setting `strict=true`. I want to correctly export my symbols in my lib.

My test scenario is pretty simple :

- the lib exports a sayHello method

```
// helloworld.ts
export function sayHello() {
    console.log('hi')
}
```

```
// index.ts
export {sayHello} from './helloworld';
```

- the app call the sayHello method

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="showMsg">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import sayHello from "my-lib";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  methods: {
    showMsg: function() {
      sayHello();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

(The app works fine if I replace the sayHello by a direct call to console.log)

I have used `vue create` in order to generate both projects.

**On the lib side**, I have set the following config:

```
// package.json
  "name": "my-lib",
  ...
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/my-lib.common.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.ts",
    ...
```

```
// tsconfig.json
  ...
  "declaration": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "outDir": "./dist",
  ...
```

**On the appside**, I have install the app locally using `npm install "../my-lib"` (path is ok).
I understood that during the development version, it's a good option.

I guess that the problem is somewhere around the d.ts files generation. I thought that tsc was supposed to create them automatically because I'm writting typescript files.
But I can't find them. I don't have any d.ts files.

I have tried multiple stuff, like:

- calling `tsc -p tscconfig.json` manually (some d.ts appeared, but no lib, no understanding of vue files. I need to use my `build-lib` script)
- adding a `vue.config.js` (no change at all)

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      libraryExport: "default"
    }
  }
};
```

- changing names / checking names / etc.
- Found an [old but unanswered message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998121/generate-d-ts-file-for-vue-components-written-in-typescript#comment117314995_57998121)

I am kind of **a rookie in Web development** (I am an experienced software developer). I am trying to put my head around those technologies. I have this strong feeling that I'm missing something with this TypeScript thing. And I might have some c++ reflexes when it comes to symbols exposure in libraries. I don't know.

I can provide more infos, more code portion, etc. I didn't want to be too invasive :)

Thanks you all in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declaration: true` in `tsconfig.json` is *supposed* to work, but there's an outstanding blocking issue ([`vue-cli#1081`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1081)).

The workaround is to run `tsc` to generate the type declarations:

1. Update `tsconfig.json` to set `compilerOptions.outDir="dist"`:

   ```js
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "dist"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update `package.json`'s build script to include the `tsc` command for generating type declarations:

   ```js
   {
     "scripts": {
       "build-lib": "vue-cli-service build --target lib src/index.ts && tsc --emitDeclarationOnly -p tsconfig.json"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Update `package.json` to specify the `main` script, and `types` for the type declaration file:

   ```js
   {
     "main": "dist/my-lib.umd.js",
     "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
   }
   ```

Comment: Your project [works fine for me](https://imgur.com/a/DAYIQla) (I see all exported types for `my-lib` and get IntelliSense for `sayHello` and `helloMessage`). If you're using VS Code and you have the project open before installing dependencies, make sure to restart VS Code after installing the dependencies, or else you won't see the types from `my-lib`. I noticed that problem myself.