# How do I add types to a Vite library build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, rollup, vite

I followed the vite documentation for using [library mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode) and I am able to produce a working component library.
I created the project with the **vue-ts**  preset and in my component I have defined props with their types, and used some interfaces. But when I build the library, there are no types included.

How do I add types for the final build, either inferred from components automatically or manually with definition files?

**More information**
Here is some more information on my files:
`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "name": "@mneelansh/test-lib",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "emitDeclarationOnly": true, // testing
  "declaration": true, // testing
  "main": "./dist/lib.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/lib.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/main.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/lib.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/lib.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.25",
    "vue": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.9.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.7"
  }
}
```

I added the `emitDeclarationOnly` and `declaration` properties but that didn't help.

My `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

const path = require("path");

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
      name: "Button",
      fileName: (format) => `lib.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. What are you running. What does your tsconfig look like?

Comment: By default, Vite strips out the types, it's meant to speed up the processing pipeline. But what about using `tsc`  with the `--emitDeclarationOnly` flag?

Comment: Try this `npm install vite @vitejs/plugin-vue --save-dev`

Comment: @tauzN Please look at the tsconfig and vite config, I've added that in the question now

Comment: see also [Type definitions are not generated for library mode build #2049](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2049)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`vite-plugin-dts`](https://github.com/qmhc/vite-plugin-dts)

```js
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
```

Comment: Tried a few things now. This was the only thing that really did the Job, Thanks :)

Comment: note, this is slow. build is faster with `rollup` and `rollup-plugin-typescript2`, about 4x faster in my case. there is also [vite-dts](https://github.com/alloc/vite-dts) but its broken. alternative: `npx tsup src/index.ts --format cjs,esm --dts` - faster than rollup, 80% of time is needed for dts

Comment: The way this plugin handles types is different from `vue-tsc`, so it may report some strange bugs....

Comment: vite-plugin-dts has issue as of now. it doesn't generate types in dev mode and deletes types on every alternative run.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I think a nicer way to do it is with vue-tsc:

```
vue-tsc --declaration --emitDeclarationOnly
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70343443/398287

Comment: Thanks for the input. Vite-plugin-dts actually works very nicely. Have to try vue-tsc with Vite to see how well it would work

Comment: @NeelanshMathur does vite-plugin-dts show typescript errors for you? I see it has some advantages but even if i put something like `const a:number = "string"` in my code, it wouldn't show any error. ....which was a problem.

Comment: The plugin purely produces declaration files. Errors depend on your environment. If you need an example, you can see my published library https://github.com/neelansh15/vue-connect-wallet

Answer (score 2):

Usually with vite and typescript project you need add type checking before build, because vite doesn't do it by himself. Here I'm also using `vite-plugin-dts` as in post from Julien Kode, and for type checking `rollup-plugin-typescript2`.

Finally my `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';
import rollupTs from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        Vue(),
        dts({ insertTypesEntry: true }),
        // only for type checking
        {
            ...rollupTs({
                check: true,
                tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
                tsconfigOverride: {
                    noEmits: true,
                },
            }),
            // run before build
            enforce: 'pre',
        },
    ],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
        lib: {
            entry: './src/index.ts',
            fileName: 'index',
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
            // into your library
            external: [
                'vue',
                'vue-class-component',
                'vue-property-decorator',
                'vuex',
                'vuex-class',
            ],
            output: {
                // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
                // for externalized deps
                globals: {
                    vue: 'Vue',
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own Vite plugin to leverage `tsc` at the `buildEnd` step to accomplish this. As other answers have suggested, you can use the flag `emitDeclarationOnly`.

See this simple example:

```
import { type Plugin } from 'vite';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

const dts: Plugin = {
  name: 'dts-generator',
  buildEnd: (error?: Error) => {
    if (!error) {
      return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        exec('tsc --emitDeclarationOnly', (err) => (err ? rej(err) : res()));
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Then add to your `plugins` field of your vite config