# get rid of folder prefix in declare module typescript type files

Tags: typescript

So my project structure looks like this:

```
src/
  button/
    j-button.ts
    j-button.test.ts
```

And I build my project in vite which outputs

```
dist/
  j-button.js
```

then I have

```json
"types": "index.d.ts"
```

in my component lib `package.json`

But my index.d.ts file that `tsc --outFile index.d.ts` outputs looks like this:

```
declare module "button/j-button" {
 ...
}
```

and I think thats breaking my types because the import in the consuming app looks like this:

```
import JButton from '@jump/components/dist/j-button'
```

and so I assume typescript is looking for a `declare module "dist/j-button"` instead of `button/j-button` right?

How do I configure typescript to call these modules the right thing?

Comment: Shouldn't vite be generating declaration files?

Comment: kinda seems like vite doesn't do it for library mode. I'm just using the build command that came with the template `"build": "tsc --outFile index.d.ts && vite build"`, but this suggests another way of doing it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982849/how-do-i-add-types-to-a-vite-library-build